# Checking if scanned file has letters from alphabet array, and counting occurrences to another array

Tags: java, arrays

I filled an array with the alphabet, and created another array that will be used to count the occurrences of each letter in a .txt file.

The lettersLabels array is a String type, because my teacher premade a bar chart code with lettersLabels being String. The same also goes for lettersFrequency being double. My teacher also asked us to use a scanner to scan the file line by line.

I need help on making the code scan the line, checking if each letter is part of the lettersLabels array, then taking that letters value and adding it into the lettersFrequency array.

Below I have gotten to the if loop for checking if the letters are part of the array. I couldn't figure out how to add the counter to the vaules of lettersFrequency array.

Sorry if this isn't enough information, I am new to Java/coding.

```
        // Array for lowercase alphabet with ascii
        String[] lettersLabels = new String[26];
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                lettersLabels[i] = String.valueOf((char)(97 + i));
            }
        // Creates Array for frequency of letters occurrence 
        double[] lettersFrequency = new double[26];
        
        // Scanner for .txt Files
        File inputFile = new File(FILE_NAME);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);
        
         // While loop to scan file line by line for letters in lettersLabels array, counting occurrences, and adding to lettersFrequency array.

         while (scan.hasNext()) {
             String readFile = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();
             for (int i = 0; i < readFile.length()-1; i++) {
                 if (readFile = lettersLabels[i]) { // Don't know if this works
                     // Need help with adding counter here.
                 }
             }
         }
         
         scan.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the count of a value in the frequency array using `lettersFrequency[letterNumber] += 1;`, however, you will need to correct your for loop as follows and do correct string checking. Read my notation below to see the changes made:

```
 //Remove the -1 from this line, otherwise the last letter of your line won't be checked, you already use < instead of <= so the -1 is not necessary
 for (int i = 0; i < readFile.length(); i++) {
     //Add a new loop to check the 26 possible letters
     for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++) {
         //Use readFile.charAt(i) to get the current char in the line
         //And use .equals(...) to compare the current character to the one in your lettersLabels array
         //Note that we need to add +"" after charAt(i) to convert it back to a string
         if (lettersLabels[x].equals(readFile.charAt(i)+"")) {
             //Finally incriment count by 1 for any matched letters
             lettersFrequency[x] += 1;
         }    
     }
 }
```

Comment: Updated my answer to fix the if statement that was failing because a char is not equal to a String

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the character as an index to increment values in `lettersFrequency`.

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String readFile = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    for(char c : readFile.toCharArray()) {
         if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
             int index = c - 97;
             //int index = Character.getNumericValue(c)-10;
             lettersFrequency[index]++;
         }
   }
}
```

Or you can use [Character.getNumericValue(char)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) method.